# UnsupportedClassVersionError jdk 1.8

Tags: spring, java-8

When I run my project I get the following errors. My jdk is currently 1.8. To fix it, I have tried resetting the jdk, downgrading to 1.7, I've checked my buildpaths, I've gone into preferences and restored to defaults and it's the same error. I've deleted and reinstalled the jdk as well.

In regards to the error about JavaLaunchHelper I found a question on here that said it's a bug that isn't fixed in 1.8 and that it can be ignored as they are actually in the right place.

My IDE is Spring Tool Suite and I'm writing in Spring Data.

Any help is appreciated, thanks!

```
objc[8419]: Class JavaLaunchHelper is implemented in both           /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_79.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java and        /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_79.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/libinstrument.dylib. One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: io/pivotal/ticket/RuleControllerTest : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:800)
at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:449)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:71)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.loadClass(RemoteTestRunner.java:685)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.loadClasses(RemoteTestRunner.java:421)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:444)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:675)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)
```

Comment: `jdk1.7.0_79` is definitely not `1.8`. So you shouldn’t be surprised that it can’t run code requiring `1.8`.

Comment: I have checked this and my compiler is using 1.8, I am aware of the differences. I had to change to 1.8 a few weeks ago because my project required it - I didn't make any jdk changes and then the error appeared about jdk1.7. According to several forums I've found about that error there is an issue with the jdk that makes the error appear but that shouldn't actually affect the code - the UnsupportedClassVersion error appears to be a separate issue.

Comment: I have no idea what other issue you are talking about, when you say “the UnsupportedClassVersion error appears to be a separate issue” as that’s the *only* issue you are mentioning in your question. And your posted log clearly shows that you are trying to run the application in `jdk1.7.0_79`.

Comment: The error in the first paragraph is the one that I've been told is a bug and have checked and it is 1.8 that is bring used - I cannot find anywhere that 1.7 is being used. The error I'm talking about in the second paragraph appeared after the first, and seems to be a different issue.

Comment: In your first paragraph, you are not describing an error at all. You are saying “I get the following errors”, but then, no error description follows. Instead, you are describing what you have tried to fix the undescribed error(s). In the second paragraph you are saying something about “error about JavaLaunchHelper” which you then describe as bug that you can ignore, so it doesn’t seem to be your issue. So what remains, is the `UnsupportedClassVersionError` having an obvious cause as the log clearly refers to `/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_79.jdk/…`.

Answer (score 1):

The class `io/pivotal/ticket/RuleControllerTest` has been compiled using Java 1.8, but you are trying to run it using Java 1.7 (or earlier). You should check your run config. Since this is being run from Eclipse's test runner, you need to either change the run config for that or run Eclipse using JDK 1.8.

Comment: I am using Spring tool suite and while I've found the compiler settings in the preferences section, I can't seem to find how to change the run config? Thank you.